# Counter up function stop when scroll and show error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm receiving this error every time I scroll towards my counter up function -> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shift' of null at f (jquery.counterup.js:62)". Any idea how to fix it ?

Here's the code:

```js
$('.counter').counterUp({
  delay: 10,
  time: 2000
});
$('.counter').addClass('animated fadeInDownBig');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.3/css/solid.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Counter-Up/1.0.0/jquery.counterup.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid padding text-center counter-group">
  <div class="row padding">
    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-users"></i><br>
      <span class="counter">5000</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Clients</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i><br>
      <span class="counter">2200</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Projects</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-building"></i><br>
      <span class="counter">8600</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Registered Properties </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-medal"></i><br>
      <span class="counter">100</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Achievements</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid padding text-center counter-group">
  <div class="row padding">
    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-users"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">5000</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Clients</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">2200</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Projects</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-building"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">8600</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Registered Properties </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-medal"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">100</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Achievements</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid padding text-center counter-group">
  <div class="row padding">
    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-users"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">5000</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Clients</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">2200</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Projects</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-building"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">8600</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Registered Properties </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-medal"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">100</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Achievements</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid padding text-center counter-group">
  <div class="row padding">
    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-users"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">5000</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Clients</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">2200</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Projects</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-building"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">8600</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Registered Properties </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-medal"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">100</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Achievements</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid padding text-center counter-group">
  <div class="row padding">
    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-users"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">5000</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Clients</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">2200</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Projects</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-building"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">8600</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Registered Properties </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-medal"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">100</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Achievements</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid padding text-center counter-group">
  <div class="row padding">
    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-users"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">5000</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Clients</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">2200</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Projects</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-building"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">8600</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Registered Properties </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
      <i class="fas fa-medal"></i><br>
      <span class="counter1">100</span><span>+</span>
      <div class="text">Achievements</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have created a snippet and added some values to create the possibility to scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have upgraded the version of counterUp and no problem: instead version 1.0.0, use the 2.1.0.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery.counterup@2.1.0/jquery.counterup.js"></script>
```

```js
$('.counter').counterUp({
  delay: 10,
  time: 2000
});
$('.counter').addClass('animated fadeInDownBig');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.3/css/solid.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery.counterup@2.1.0/jquery.counterup.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid padding text-center counter-group">
      <div class="row padding">
        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-users"></i><br>
          <span class="counter">5000</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Clients</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i><br>
          <span class="counter">2200</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Projects</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-building"></i><br>
          <span class="counter">8600</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Registered Properties </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
         <i class="fas fa-medal"></i><br>
         <span class="counter">100</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Achievements</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid padding text-center counter-group">
      <div class="row padding">
        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-users"></i><br>
          <span class="counter1">5000</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Clients</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i><br>
          <span class="counter1">2200</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Projects</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-building"></i><br>
          <span class="counter1">8600</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Registered Properties </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
         <i class="fas fa-medal"></i><br>
         <span class="counter1">100</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Achievements</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid padding text-center counter-group">
      <div class="row padding">
        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-users"></i><br>
          <span class="counter1">5000</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Clients</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i><br>
          <span class="counter1">2200</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Projects</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-building"></i><br>
          <span class="counter1">8600</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Registered Properties </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
         <i class="fas fa-medal"></i><br>
         <span class="counter1">100</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Achievements</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid padding text-center counter-group">
      <div class="row padding">
        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-users"></i><br>
          <span class="counter1">5000</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Clients</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i><br>
          <span class="counter1">2200</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Projects</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-building"></i><br>
          <span class="counter1">8600</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Registered Properties </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
         <i class="fas fa-medal"></i><br>
         <span class="counter1">100</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Achievements</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid padding text-center counter-group">
      <div class="row padding">
        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-users"></i><br>
          <span class="counter1">5000</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Clients</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i><br>
          <span class="counter1">2200</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Projects</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-building"></i><br>
          <span class="counter1">8600</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Registered Properties </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
         <i class="fas fa-medal"></i><br>
         <span class="counter1">100</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Achievements</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid padding text-center counter-group">
      <div class="row padding">
        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-users"></i><br>
          <span class="counter1">5000</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Clients</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i><br>
          <span class="counter1">2200</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Projects</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
          <i class="fas fa-building"></i><br>
          <span class="counter1">8600</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Registered Properties </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 content reveal">
         <i class="fas fa-medal"></i><br>
         <span class="counter1">100</span><span>+</span>
          <div class="text">Achievements</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it work just fine know for me, thankyou very much for your comment